# Calling a VB5 ActiveX DLL Function from C# Gives EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I have a very short VB5 DLL that I am trying to call from VS2015 C#.  I compiled the VB5 project as an ActiveX DLL and copied the DLL into a library folder where VS could find it.

I am getting an execution exception that VS can't find the function inside the DLL, and I do not know how to fix it.  I have searched many of the queries here in StackOverflow, and tried implementing their fixes, but so far, none has worked.  They were written for a different version of VB, or of Visual Studios, or I did what the answerer recommended, but it didn't fix my problem.

VB5 Project info:

- Project name:  VBHW (VB_HW.vbp)
- Class modules: VB_Hello_World (VB_Hello_World.cls)

Contents of VB_HW.vbp:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function VB_Fn(ByVal x As Long) As Long

VB_Fn = 1000 + x

End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

C# Form.  This form is generated when a certain button on a certain form is clicked.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IR_Trap_Phase_I
{
    public partial class TempForm : Form
    {
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        public TempForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        [DllImport("VB_HW.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern long VB_Fn(long x);

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long returned = 0;
            returned = Call_VB_Fn();
            MessageBox.Show("  in TempForm: Got " + returned.ToString("n0") + " back from call to VB.", "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }


        public static long Call_VB_Fn()
        {
            long returned_long = 0;
            long outgoing_long = 1015;

            MessageBox.Show("In USB_Ops.Call_VB_Fn: about to call VB_Fn." + Environment.NewLine +
                "   outgoing_long = " + outgoing_long.ToString("n0") + " and returned_long = <" + returned_long + ">." + Environment.NewLine +
                "   Drum roll please)...",
                "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            returned_long = VB_Fn(outgoing_long);


            MessageBox.Show("LOOK LOOK LOOK: " + Environment.NewLine +
                "   outgoing_long = " + outgoing_long.ToString("n0") + " and VB_Fn = <" + returned_long + "> -- SHOULD BE 2015.",
                "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return (outgoing_long);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the execution error at the line

```
      returned_long = VB_Fn(outgoing_long);
```

The error message that I'm getting is:

> "Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in IR_Trapper_Phase_I_Ass.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'VB_Fn' in DLL 'F:\SBIR\VS2015\IR_Trap_Phase_I\IR_Trap_Phase_I\obj\Debug\Interop.VBHW.dll'."

So VS found my Project Reference correctly and is finding the DLL file, but can't find the VB_Fn function inside the DLL file.

Additional clues:

- If I go to VS, click inside the function, and type "VBHW.",       Intellisense provides the options "VB_Hello_World" and       "VB_Hello_World_Class".
- However, choosing either "VB_Hello_World" or "VB_Hello_World_Class" only gives the options "Equals" and "ReferenceEquals".

  Which tends to support the error message (can't find VB_Fn).

Can someone give me suggestions on how to make it execute correctly?

Postscript.  You may be wondering why I'm trying to make a VB5 DLL callable from VS2015 in C#.  The reason is that I have been put on a project with several thousand lines of VB5 project code already written and working.  If I can use the VB5 code in a DLL as-is, and avoid rewriting all that code in C#, I will be a hero.

This scenario is a quick, short way of finding out if it's possible to call VB5 code from a VS2015 C#.

Comment: the VB5 DLL probably returns Int32 not a NET long; same for the `x` param

Comment: I agree with Plutonix about your improper mapping of VB to .Net types, but I am confused a bit by your comment "VS found my Project Reference correctly".  Are you adding a project reference to the library that is generating an interop assembly in addition to the `DllImport` function?

Comment: @Plutonix:  Thanks for pointing out the type mismatch.  Good eye!

Comment: @TnTinMn.  Thanks for replying to my question.  "VS found my Project Reference correctly" means:

1. I copied VBHW.dll into the library folder in which I store all the dlls the C# program needs to reference.

2 In VS, under Solution Explorer, under the project name, I right-clicked References, Add, and clicked on VBHW.dll.  I did not get any error messages from Visual Studios, so I **assume** that VS "found" VBHW.dll, did whatever checking it does when a user adds a reference file, and concluded that the dll was valid.

Comment: @ColleenKobe, sorry, I forgot to check back on this.  If you successfully added the dll as a project reference it will be shown in the References node in the Solution Explorer (SE).  To see the references in SE, you need to click on the button, "Show All Files" at the top of the SE.   Based on your comment about `...I\obj\Debug\Interop.VBHW.dll`, you have successfully referenced the ActiveX dll and VS has created an Interop dll for you and you do not need to use the 'DllImport - Function` syntax.  You would create an instance of the `VB_Hello_World.cls' and call the function on that instance.